# Error occurring in Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC while connecting to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

`Student` class :

```
public class Students
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Fname { get; set; }
        public string Lname { get; set; }
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
        //on one to many relationship Student can have many enrollments so its a collection of Enrollments
        public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

Enrollment :

```
public enum Grade
{
    A, B, C, D, F
}

public class Enrollment
{    
        public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        public int StudentID { get; set; }

        //? will take the default value, to avoid null expections as object value not set, if the grade not above theen also passes with out any errors.
        public Grade? Grade { get; set; }

        //single enrollment has  single course , single we give the Courses as Class name 
        public virtual Courses Course { get; set; }

        //single enrollment has  single student, single we give the Student  as Class name 
        public virtual Students Student { get; set; }
}
```

`Courses` class :

```
public class Courses
{
        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Credits { get; set; }

        // A course has many enrollments
        public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

`Controller` - getting error at

```
db.Students.Add(objstu)
```

when I'm running the application for the first time and wanted to see autogenerated tables. But while its connecting to database am getting this error

```
public ActionResult CreateStudent(Students objstu)
{
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(objstu);
            }

            db.Students.Add(objstu);     
            return View();
}
```

Error details :

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>   DAL.Courses: : EntityType 'Courses' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   Courses: EntityType: EntitySet 'Courses' is based on type 'Courses' that has no keys defined.

Comment: What happens if you use a consistent naming for your identifiers, such as `ID` for all of them?

Answer (score 3):

Your entity class name is `Courses` .But the primary key column name is `CourseID`. By convention, It should be either `ID` or *`entity class name+ID`*, which is `CoursesID`.

Either change your entity class name to `Course` or change `CourseID` property to `CoursesID`

Another option is to decorate your `CourseID` property with `[Key]` data annotation.

```
public class Courses
{
    [Key]
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
}
```

If you do not prefer to use data annotations (the above approach), You can achieve the same thing with fluent api. In your data context class, override the `OnModelCreating` method and specify which column is the key for the Courses entity class.

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{ 
  public DbSet<Courses> Courses { set; get; }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Courses>().HasKey(f => f.CourseID);
  }
}
```

Comment: Keen eye! Of course singular names are recommended.

Comment: Thank you man, it worked . I changed from CourseID to CoursesID